# How to improve performance of FOR XML PATH with large data set

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions, sqlperformance

I am attempting to use the FOR XML PATH technique of concatenating strings from a result set, but am running into some performance issues.  I'm wondering if there's any way to improve this type of query.

I am writing a query for a report that is used to check inventory balances for all 15000 rows of a `Part` table.  These parts can be used on one or many pieces of equipment stored in an `Equipment` table, which also has around 12000 rows.  The clients would like the report to have a comma separated field of the pieces of equipment on which each part is used.

I started by creating a query that returns the full join of parts and equipment

```
SELECT PartName, Balance, EquipmentName as UsedOn 
FROM Part p
    LEFT OUTER JOIN EquipmentPart ep ON p.PartID = ep.PartID
    LEFT INNER JOIN Equipment e ON ep.EquipmentID = e.EquipmentID
```

This returns a result set of 49000 rows in 1 second (according to SQL Server Management Studio) but wasn't accomplishing the end-goal.

I then tried to just focus on getting the comma separated field by doing something like the following

```
SELECT PartName, Balance, 
      STUFF((SELECT ',' + EquipmentName
        FROM Equipment e JOIN EquipmentPart ep ON e.EquipmentID = ep.EquipmentID
        WHERE ep.PartID = p.PartID
        FOR XML PATH('')) as UsedOn
FROM Part p
```

This took over 8 minutes before I finally killed it; it had only made it through 8000 of the 15000 rows.

My current solution combines the first query with the FOR XML PATH sub-query

```
WITH PartBalances AS
(SELECT PartID, PartName, Balance, EquipmentName as UsedOn 
FROM Part p
    LEFT OUTER JOIN EquipmentPart ep ON p.PartID = ep.PartID
    LEFT INNER JOIN Equipment e ON ep.EquipmentID = e.EquipmentID
)
SELECT PartName, Balance,
       STUFF ((SELECT ',' + UsedOn
        FROM PartBalances p2
        WHERE p1.PartID = p2.PartID
        FOR XML PATH(''))
FROM PartBalances p1
GROUP BY PartID, PartName, Balance
```

This does seem to return what I want, but it takes a minute to do.  One minute is sort of acceptable, but I was hoping for something a lot better.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong or stupidly?  Is there a way to avoid making 15000 sub-queries?

Comment: i think slow performance due to left outer join you should not use left outer join

Comment: Sorry, the left outer join in the long-running query was a copy-paste error.  I'm simplifying the query from my actual environment.

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH PartBalances AS
(SELECT PartID, PartName, Balance, EquipmentName as UsedOn 
FROM Part p
    JOIN EquipmentPart ep ON p.PartID = ep.PartID
    JOIN Equipment e ON ep.EquipmentID = e.EquipmentID
)
SELECT PartName, Balance,
       STUFF ((SELECT ',' + UsedOn
        FROM PartBalances p2
        WHERE p1.PartID = p2.PartID
        FOR XML PATH(''))
FROM PartBalances p1
GROUP BY PartID, PartName, Balance
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try running this version of the query?

```
SELECT PartName, Balance, 
       STUFF((SELECT ',' + EquipmentName
              FROM EquipmentPart ep JOIN
                   Equipment e
                   ON e.EquipmentID = ep.EquipmentID
              WHERE ep.PartID = p.PartID
              FOR XML PATH('')
             ), 1, 1, '') as UsedOn
FROM Part p;
```

The `LEFT JOIN` could be confusing the optimizer.

Comment: Sorry, the LEFT JOIN in the sub-query was a copy-paste issue from me trying to simplify my real-world query.  My actual, super slow query does use just JOIN.

Comment: @MattJ . . . Create an index on `EquipmentPart(PartId, EquipmentId)`.  I am guessing you already have an index on `EquipmentPart(EquipmentId, PartId)`.